# Kafka Producer Recovery Strategy when consuming a parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a use case, where I have to read parquet files and publish the records towards a kafka topic.

I read the parquet files using :

```
spark.read.schema(//path to parquet file )
```

Then I sort this dataframe based on the timestamp (use case specific requirements to preserve order)
Finally, I do the following :

binaryFiles below is the dataframe containing the sorted records from the parquet file

```
binaryFiles.coalesce(1).foreachPartition(partition => {
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,Array[Byte]](properties)
    partition.foreach(file => {
      try {  
         var producerRecord = new ProducerRecord[String,Array[Byte]](targetTopic,file.getAs[Integer](2),file.getAs[String](0),file.getAs[Array[Byte]](1))
          var metadata = producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback {
                                  override def onCompletion(recordMetadata:RecordMetadata , e:Exception):Unit = {
                                      if (e != null){
                                          println ("Error while producing" +  e);
                                          producer.close()
                                      }
                                  }
                              }); 
              producer.flush()          
        }
      catch{
          case  unknown :Throwable =>  println("Exception obtained with record. Key :  " + unknown)
          }      
    })
  producer.close() 
  println("Closing the producer for this partition")
  })
```

While writing the failover strategy for this scenario, one scenario that I am trying to cater to is what if the node that runs the kafka producer goes down.

Now when the kafka producer is restarted it will again read the parquet file from start and start publishing all the records again to the same topic.

How can we overcome this and implement some sort of checkpointing that spark stream provides.

PS: I cannot use spark structured streaming as that does not preserve the order of the messages

Comment: You would have to store at least the name of the file and the number of records from the beginning that have been sent and acknowledged. Where you store that information, and how, is up to you. Zookeeper is one option. Or you could add a field, like a timestamp in the data, then you can work around the ordering problems

Comment: @cricket_007 : The data already has a timestamp column. I did try out the spark structured streaming to see if that can be an option. Upon examining carefully, the order is preserved within the partition, but across partitions , thats debatable.

Comment: sorry.. sent early by mistake.. `.option("checkpointLocation",checkPointLocation)` - trying to use checkpoint from kafka stream (batch), however, it does send the entire recordset from the parquet file again. Not sure how does this checkpoint helps.

Comment: `val topic = "SSOrder2"
val checkPointLocation = "adl://<<azure_data_lake_Store>>/CheckPoints/OrderTest" + topic

binaryFiles.coalesce(1).write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",servers")
    .option("topic",topic)
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512")
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
    .option("kafka.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", "1")
    .option("checkpointLocation",checkPointLocation)
    .save()`